# error: Can't find/load main class

Tags: java, cmd

I'm new to coding and I'm trying to run my helloworld script in the command prompt and it keeps saying it can't find or load the main class. I used eclipse to write the code and i can see the main class in the run configurations, but when i put that in it says the same thing. 
  Here's the code.

```
    package helloworld;

public class helloworld {


public static void main(String[] args) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
System.out.println("Hello World!");
//display the string
}

}
```

Comment: what is your file name? It should be same as your class name.

Comment: its the same as the package and class name.

Comment: Are you running from CMD, or eclipse? Why is the package name the same as the class name? Why is the class name not in the form `CapitalzedWords`?

Comment: I'm coding in eclipse and running it in the cmd. i didn't know they had to be different

Comment: They can be the same, but you should 1) Create a **Java Project** in Eclipse. 2) Write code in the `(default package)`, or make one 3) Use the Green run button in Eclipse.

Answer (score 0):

When running java main class from the command line you want to go to root directory of the project and run the class using FQN (Fully qualified name). like so:

```
java helloworld.helloworld
```

This assumes that your project is in i.e

```
C:/eclipse/workspace/helloworld <- root directory of the project
```

and you execute the above 'java' command from that root directory

Points to make:

1. Class name should be CAPITALIZED so `HelloWorld` or `Helloworld`
2. Its Bad practice to have class name the same as package name. Its allowed just bad practice

**EDIT:**

Fully Qualified Name consists of all the packages in the tree + the class file you want to run.

So for example if the class you want to run from CMD is in:

```
C:/eclipse/workspace/helloworld/com/mysubfolder/folder/mainclass
```

Your root directory of the the project is in:

```
C:/eclipse/workspace/helloworld
```

So from that directory, you need to run the following command

```
java com.mysubfolder.folder.mainclass
```

Comment: how do you get the FQN?

Comment: FQN is basically a packagename.classname

Comment: i got the right directory and I'm able to run it without the error code but now its asking for another app to open it in.